# Svelte: select text of input element on focus

Tags: typescript, svelte

I want to select the text of the `input` element on focus. I tried with `bind:this={ref}` and then `ref.select()`, but this seems only to work when i remove the `bind:value` from the `input` element. Why? and how to solve?

Many thanks!

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { evaluate } from 'mathjs';

    export let value: string | number = 0;
    let ref;

    function handleFocus() {
        value = value?.toString().replace('.', '').replace(',', '.');
        ref.select();
    }

    function handleBlur() {
        value = parseFloat(evaluate(value?.toString())).toLocaleString('be-NL', {
            maximumFractionDigits: 2,
            minimumFractionDigits: 2
        });
    }
</script>

<input
    class="text-right"
    autocomplete="off"
    type="text"
    bind:value
    bind:this={ref}
    on:focus={handleFocus}
    on:blur={handleBlur}
/>
```

Comment: I think it's because you're changing the value that you are binding to right before trying to select the text. If you remove the `value = value?.toString().replace('.', '').replace(',', '.');` part it should select. Alternatively you can do a `setTimeout(()=> ref.select(), 0)` or use `await tick()` and make your function async and it should work fine even with the change right before `select()`.

Comment: `await tick()` works perfect! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by the comment of @JHeth:
I added `await tick()`, made the function `async` and it worked.

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { evaluate } from 'mathjs';

    export let value: string | number = 0;
    let ref;

    async function handleFocus() {
        value = value?.toString().replace('.', '').replace(',', '.');
        await tick();
        ref.select();
    }

    function handleBlur() {
        value = parseFloat(evaluate(value?.toString())).toLocaleString('be-NL', {
            maximumFractionDigits: 2,
            minimumFractionDigits: 2
        });
    }
</script>

<input
    class="text-right"
    autocomplete="off"
    type="text"
    bind:value
    bind:this={ref}
    on:focus={async () => handleFocus()}
    on:blur={handleBlur}
/>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do it inline in the input tag:

```
<input on:focus="{event => event.target.select()}">
```

or pass the event to a function and do more stuff:

```
<script>
    function selectContentAndDoStuff (event) {
        console.log("event: ", event);
        event.target.select();
        console.log("do more stuff here")
    }
</script>

<input on:focus="{event => selectContentAndDoStuff(event)}">
```

Comment: Just use `on:focus={(evt) => evt.target.select()}`